# Command Line Install Doesn't Work in 16.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, 16.04

I'm trying to learn about customizing the preseed file for an automated install of Ubuntu 16.04 Server. To test, I type ESC, ESC, ENTER as the installer starts up to get to the "boot:" prompt. When I enter the boot command, which is quite long, something inserts a line break every 80 characters. And the boot command doesn't appear to do what I want.

[Edit: I'm pretty sure the line breaks inserted by the installer are a red herring. See my answer for what I did to make this work.]

If I do the exact same thing with the 14.04.04 Server .iso, there are no line breaks, and the install works as expected. I.E. takes values from the preseed file.

I have done this both manually, and using Packer, and get the same results: installing with the 14.04 .iso works, the 16.04 .iso puts in extra line breaks and doesn't work.

For the record, I'm installing into a VirtualBox VM on an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I also tried it with a QEMU VM on an Ubuntu 14.04 host, and observed the same behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the 16.04 installer has a new command-line way to enter installer boot parameters. It's a single line near the bottom of the screen. You can edit this line by pressing F6 when you're on the screen with the installer options, starting with "Install Ubuntu Server." Using this line allows you to enter a long list of boot parameters. It scrolls horizontally.

So if you're using Packer, the example `template.json` files you'll find on the Internet for Serv 14.04 won't work. Here's the "builders" section that I used, which works:

```
   "builders": [{
    "type": "virtualbox-iso",
    "boot_command": [
      "<enter><f6><esc>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs>",
      "auto preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg ",
      "debian-installer=en_CA locale=en_CA kbd-chooser/method=us ",
      "hostname=rails-5-jade ",
      "fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive ",
      "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA ",
      "keyboard-configuration/variant=USA console-setup/ask_detect=false ",
      "vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --- ",
      "<enter>"
    ],
    "boot_wait": "4s",
    "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
    "http_directory": "http",
    "iso_checksum": "23e97cd5d4145d4105fbf29878534049",
    "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
    "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso",
    "ssh_username": "vagrant",
    "ssh_password": "vagrant",
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
    "disk_size": "8000",
    "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
    "vboxmanage": [
      [
        "modifyvm",
        "{{.Name}}",
        "--memory",
        "512"
      ],
      [
        "modifyvm",
        "{{.Name}}",
        "--cpus",
        "1"
      ]
    ]
   }],
```

You can also look at one of my projects in Github: https://github.com/lcreid/rails-5-jade.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was scratching my head and search a lot before finding this working answer, I guess I didn't have the proper keywords...